# How to implement SCORM player with react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

Is there a way to create a simple SCORM player to load all the SCORM content that can play and track the progress. I have tried using HTMl and javascript, but that does not work as per expectations. Neither so I found any complete example for the available libraries.

So is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build/buy a SCORM Runtime API.

General breakdown -

1. A SCORM Package (zip) w/ imsmanifest.xml
2. Parse the imsmanifest.xml into something you want to use (JSON or otherwise)
3. Typically an assignment / registration occurs of this content.
4. From it you'll know the SCORM Version.

Create a Runtime API for SCORM 1.2 or 2004.
Set the CMI Student Attempt object.
Launch the content.
Content will seek out your API.

I've had folks implement this in Electron and Ionic but I don't know of anyone doing a react native app yet.  For this I would research "React Native JavaScript Bridge" as a tip.

You can hand roll one, but I'd caution it can take a while to fully flesh out the entire standard.

I have more info up on https://cybercussion.com/products/scobotrte